# Element not found in native angular unit testing

Tags: mocha.js, appium, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to test my native angular application using "Mocha"& "Appium".simple test case is executed successfully, but facing issue while finding a UI element.

**Error: "Error: [waitForElementByClassName("android.widget.Button",5000)] Element condition wasn't satisfied!"**

sample.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { AppiumDriver, createDriver, SearchOptions, nsCapabilities } from "nativescript-dev-appium";
import { assert } from "chai";
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');

describe("sample scenario", async () => {
    let driver: AppiumDriver;
    before(async function(){
        driver = await createDriver();
        nsCapabilities.testReporter.context = this; 
    });

    after(async function () {      
        console.log("Quit driver!");
    });

    afterEach(async function () {
        if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
            await driver.logTestArtifacts(this.currentTest.title);
        }
    });  
    it("should find an element by type",  async function () {    
       let button = await driver.findElementByClassName(driver.locators.button);
       console.log('button ',button);
        const message = "customLogOut";

        console.log('button.text()',button.text());
        assert.equal(-1,-1); // simple condition working fine.
       assert.equal(await button.text(),message);
    });
});
```

**appium.capabilities.json**

```
{

    "android18": {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": "9.0",
        "deviceName": "Pixel_2_XL_API_27",
        "avd": "Pixel_2_XL_API_27",
        "lt": 60000,
        "newCommandTimeout": 720,
        "noReset": false,
        "fullReset": false,
        "app": "../platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <Button  col="1" automationText="customLogOut" id="customLogOut"  row='3' tap="" text="customLogOut"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing application need to be installed on the emulator or device.I have three virtual devices and I had installed the application on another device and testing it on a different device that's why UI element was not found.So Using "tns run android --device "